# xls/xlsx extentions not associated properly (considered as archives)

Tags: mime-type, file-association, xls

For some reason, `xls/xslx` files are associated with `file-roller` app (for archives) and cannot be associated separately with `WPS`.

As I understand, these extentions are same MIME types with different extentions. How to associate these with different apps?

These are relavant lines from `~/.local/share/applications/mimeapps.list`

---

```
application/vnd.ms-excel=wps-office-et.desktop
application/msexcel=wps-office-et.desktop
application/x-msexcel=wps-office-et.desktop
application/x-ms-excel=wps-office-et.desktop
application/x-excel=wps-office-et.desktop
application/x-dos_ms_excel=wps-office-et.desktop
application/xls=wps-office-et.desktop
application/x-xls=wps-office-et.desktop
application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet=wps-office-et.desktop
```

File-foller is associated only with these:

```
application/x-arj=file-roller.desktop
application/x-ar=file-roller.desktop
application/x-arj=file-roller.desktop
application/x-bzip-compressed-tar=file-roller.desktop
application/x-bzip=file-roller.desktop
application/x-compressed-tar=file-roller.desktop
application/x-compress=file-roller.desktop
application/x-ear=file-roller.desktop
application/x-gtar=file-roller.desktop
application/x-gzip=file-roller.desktop
application/x-lha=file-roller.desktop
application/x-lhz=file-roller.desktop
application/x-lzop=file-roller.desktop
application/x-rar=file-roller.desktop
application/x-rpm=file-roller.desktop
multipart/x-zip=file-roller.desktop
application/x-rar-compressed=file-roller.desktop
application/x-tar=file-roller.desktop
application/x-war=file-roller.desktop
application/x-zip-compressed=file-roller.desktop
application/x-zip=file-roller.desktop
application/x-zoo=file-roller.desktop
application/zip=file-roller.desktop
```

Any ideas what's wrong?

Answer (score 0):

OK, according to this [link](https://forum.peppermintos.com/index.php?topic=1459.0) it might have been just a `pcmanfm` bug. How disappointing.